# how to display a new root category except default category in magento 2.1?

Tags: category, magento2.1.0

I got to display the same menu as the header menu on sidebar and I created another root category in admin. now I want to display the new root category's subcategories in the main menu(header menu).I am new to Magento and PHP programming. I would really appreciate it if someone tells me what to do step by step. I know I need to override some php classes for Mageno_Theme module which creates the header menu but I do not know how to do that.